# what is wrong with my file writing in c++/cx for metro app?

Tags: microsoft-metro, local-storage, c++-cx

I am using the following code to try to write to a file:

```
StorageFolder ^localFolder = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;
concurrency::task<StorageFile^> fileOperation = localFolder->CreateFileAsync("data.txt", CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting);
fileOperation.then([this](StorageFile^ sampleFile)
{
    ::Globalization::DateTimeFormatting::DateTimeFormatter("longtime");
    Platform::String ^str; // other str stuff here

    return FileIO::WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, str);
}).then([this](concurrency::task<void> previousOperation) {
    try {
        previousOperation.get();
    } catch (Platform::Exception^) {
    }
});
```

fixed the error thanks to 'Sometimes A Developer'

I got the code from here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this line:

```
concurrency::task<StorageFile^> fileOperation = localFolder->CreateFileAsync("data.txt",
    CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting);
```

with this line:

```
concurrency::task<StorageFile^> fileOperation(localFolder->CreateFileAsync("data.txt",
    CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting));
```

Comment: thanks ... that got rid of the error ... but it doesn't create the file.. thanks anyway